# How to implement angular js graphs with json data output

Tags: json, angularjs

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $state, FirstHiveService) {

        var samplelineJsonData = [  
                            {
                                "month": "Jan",
                                "noOfUsers": "65"
                            },
                            {
                                "month": "Feb",
                                "noOfUsers": "59"
                            },
                            {
                                "month": "Mar",
                                "noOfUsers": "80"
                            },
                            {
                                "month": "Apr",
                                "noOfUsers": "81"
                            },
                            {
                                "month": "May",
                                "noOfUsers": "56"
                            },
                            {
                                "month": "Jun",
                                "noOfUsers": "55"
                            },
                            {
                                "month": "Jul",
                                "noOfUsers": "40"
                            }
                          ];                          

    var lineLabelsData = []; //, percentage2 = [], output = [percentage1, percentage2];
    for (var i = 0; i < samplelineJsonData.length; i++) {
        lineLabelsData.push(samplelineJsonData[i].month);
        //percentage2.push(samplelineJsonData[i].percentage2);
    }

    lineLabelsData = JSON.stringify(lineLabelsData);    
    $scope.labels1 =  lineLabelsData;
    $scope.series1 = ['Users'];
    $scope.data1 =  [[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]]; //lineData; //[[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40] ];      

    //Iterating thru the json output Start    

    //Iterating thru the json output End
})
```

The above code doesnt work. Please let me know whats wrong in the above ... I am not able to set the $scope.labels1 value to `JSON.stringify(lineLabelsData);`

Comment: what you want to assign in `$scope.labels1` ?

Comment: I need to assign it to the months array only which is getting composed in lineLabelsData

Comment: `lineLabelsData` this is array. ` Mainly `JSON.stringify` converts a javascript value to a `JSON` string and you are not passing the right parameter in it.

Comment: lineLabelsData contains value something like : ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"]

Comment: What is the right way to assign the same value to the $scope.labels1 ?

Comment: You should pass the value from an array. Simplest way is `array[index]` or you can iterate the array values first and then assign the desired value in `$scope.labels1`. It is bit difficult to guess which value you want to pass

Comment: I just want to convert the data in the samplelineJsonData variable to the  $scope.labels1 and  $scope.data1 to be displayed in the front end graph ... can u send me the piece of code as of how can I implement it ?

Comment: Will you please tell me how your desired output should be ? About the output strucutre which should work.

Comment: $scope.labels1 should be  ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"]  and $scope.data1 should be [[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]]

Comment: Got it ? or Any doubts still ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1opht0g1/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `model` as an `array`. You should declare your model as an array first in your `init` call. It should be

```
$scope.labels1 = [], $scope.data1 = [];
```

Make sure this variable has declared in your controller init call. After that you've iterated the values and push the results in the data then you needn't to iterate again. Try below snippet

```
for (var i = 0; i < samplelineJsonData.length; i++) {
      $scope.labels1.push(JSON.stringify(samplelineJsonData[i].month));
      $scope.data1.i = parseInt(samplelineJsonData[i].noOfUsers); //Because this is an object
}
```

Comment: Superb .. it works fine for the $scope.labels1, but doesnt work for the $scope.data1... May I know what may be the issue ?

Comment: have you declared `$scope.data1 = []` ?

Comment: see `console.log(typeof $scope.data1); `. It should not be an array that's why push is not working

Comment: Any Solution Vineeth ?

Comment: share your fiddle please

Comment: I didnt get what is fiddle ?

Comment: Is this the same thing you asked for ?

Comment: Any Solution Vineeth ?

Comment: HI Vineeth ...  any solution ?

Comment: Hi Vineeth any Solution ?

Comment: I've described both possible methods in all terms. You can see your self one thing is working but another not. You need to dig it more in your code. You're jsFiddle is not working. JsFiddle is a way to share your code with others in running mode. Where I can debug the complete code on behalf of you.

Comment: @user5496572 If you find my answer is useful for you so please upvote and mark it as accept for future uses

Comment: Ya Vineeth ... I got the solution finally ... for $scope.data1, we need to assign the object value in the following way ... $scope.data1 = [$scope.data1_obj] and $scope.data1_obj is the variable that is iterated through the for loop instead of directly iterating the $scope.data1 ...

Comment: Also Please let me know how to post html tags as a part of the question in Stack Overflow ... I am unable to post it .. as it is throwing some alert messages ... ?

Comment: @user5496572 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow. When you post only HTML, you should describe some text too.